# Inserting values in two tables using one controller in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables in my database the first one is `librarybooklot` where I want to keep record when new book is bought.

[image]

The next table is LibraryBookInventory where I want to keep record
    of individual book.

[image]

Now what I want to do is when Book name A is bought in 1st lot and number of book is 10, the record should be entered in 1st table as well as second table, in second table 10 records need to entered for 10 books with different accession number, the accession number may be +1 of previous.

this is my function in `LibBookLotDAO.cs`

```
public static bool NewLibBookLotInformation(LibBookLotDTO LibBookLotDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = @"Insert into LibBookLot 
                                (BookCode,Price,ReceivedOn,NumberOfBooks,Edition)
                            values (@BookCode,@Price,@ReceivedOn,@NumberOfBooks,@Edition ); ";
            _dbm = new DBManager();

            _dbm.CreateParameters(5);
            _dbm.AddParameters(0, "@BookCode", LibBookLotDTO.BookCode);
            _dbm.AddParameters(1, "@Price", LibBookLotDTO.Price);
            _dbm.AddParameters(2, "@ReceivedOn", LibBookLotDTO.ReceivedOn);
            _dbm.AddParameters(3, "@NumberOfBooks", LibBookLotDTO.NumberOfBooks);
            _dbm.AddParameters(4, "@Edition", LibBookLotDTO.Edition);

            int row = _dbm.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, sql);

            if (row == 0) return false;
            else return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
        finally { _dbm.Close(); }
    }
```

and this is my code in LibBookLotController.cs

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(LibBookLotDTO LibBookLotDTO)
    {
        if (LibBookLotDAO.NewLibBookLotInformation(LibBookLotDTO))
        {
            Session["INFO"] = "Successfully Added";
        }
        else
        {
            Session["ERROR"] = "Failed To Add";
        }
        return Redirect("Index?plugin=Library");
    }
```

Plz someone help me, since I am new to asp.net

Comment: you want to save a book in two tables same time, right?

Comment: yes but don't know how can I do that.....

Comment: You have a function `[Http Post]` in your controller?

Comment: yes I have that function

Comment: Can you post your view where you have the fields you want save plz